# Pass down image metadata across components

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx, react-props, use-state

I've made an image modal which enlarges an image when clicked but also I want a caption which displays the alt text. This is how the image is passed down:

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [selectImg, setSelectImg] = useState(null);

return (
    <div className="App">
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <Gallery setSelectImg={setSelectImg} />
        {selectImg && (
          <Modal selectImg={selectImg} setSelectImg={setSelectImg} />
        )}
      </Route>

    </div>
  );
}
```

**GALLERY.JSX**

```
const Gallery = ({ setSelectImg }) => {
  return (
    <div id="gallery">
      <div className="column-wrapper">
        <div>
          <img
            src={heyNoText}
            alt="Hey you"
            onClick={() => setSelectImg(heyNoText)}
          />
          <img
            src={readNoText}
            alt="Read Between My Lines"
            onClick={() => setSelectImg(readNoText)}
          />
      </div>
    </div>
```

**MODAL.JSX**

```
const Modal = ({ selectImg, setSelectImg }) => {
  const clicker = (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("backdrop")) {
      setSelectImg(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="backdrop" onClick={clicker}>
      <div className="img-caption-wrapper">
        <img src={selectImg} alt="Enlarged Img" id="modal-image" />
        <p className="caption">{selectImg.alt}</p>
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass the metadata (specifically alt text) from gallery.jsx to modal.jsx and show it in this part:

```
<p className="caption">{selectImg.alt}</p>
```

Thanks in advance!